# How can I reset all alias in powershell

Tags: command-line, bash, powershell, shell

I recently setted alias to an non command as I do not know how to use set alias. I am wondering how I can reset all alias without affecting the default alias  that come with powershell.

I tried to use `Remove-Alias` however it returned me this error :

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop\Projet\> Remove-Alias lua
Remove-Alias : The term 'Remove-Alias' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Alias lua
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-Alias:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 6):

Under powershell 5.x remove-alias is not available. So you have to use remove-item. Try this:

```
Remove-Item Alias:lua
```

Answer (score 0):

See ---

```
Name                           Value                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                   
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145                                                                           
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                 
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.145}                                                
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.145                                                                          
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                         
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                     
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                     
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                 




CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                   
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                   
...                
Function        Get-PSUPathAlias                                   2.0.8      PSUtil                                   
Function        Remove-PSFAlias                                    1.0.12     PSFramework                              
Function        Remove-PSFAlias                                    1.0.2      PSFramework                              
Function        Remove-PSUPathAlias                                2.0.8      PSUtil                                   
Function        Set-PSFTypeAlias                                   1.0.12     PSFramework                              
Function        Set-PSFTypeAlias                                   1.0.2      PSFramework                              
Function        Set-PSUPathAlias                                   2.0.8      PSUtil                                   
Cmdlet          Export-Alias                                       3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility             
Cmdlet          Get-Alias                                          3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility             
...                           
Cmdlet          Import-Alias                                       3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility             
Cmdlet          New-Alias                                          3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility             
...                           
Cmdlet          Remove-Alias                                       5.0.0.1    Sorlov.PowerShell                        
...                           
Cmdlet          Set-Alias                                          3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility             
...


Find-Module -Name '*alias*'

Version              Name                                Repository           Description                              
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                              
2.4                  ResolveAlias                        PSGallery            A function for cleaning up scripts by ...
1.0                  posh-alias                          PSGallery            A better alias for Powershell            
0.1.0                PowerShell-Core-Compatibility-Alias PSGallery            Adds aliases to PowerShell Core that w...
0.2.1                git-aliases                         PSGallery            A PowerShell module that provide parti...
1.2                  CommonAliases                       PSGallery            Common aliases for easier use.           
1.0                  rg-ps-alias                         PSGallery            Creates Alias for docker and git, see ...
0.1.1                GitAliases                          PSGallery            Automatically configures aliases for a...
1.292                Office365MailAliases                PSGallery            This module contains functions to crea...
```